# Integration with constant in function

Tags: calculus, integration

By right:
$$\int\sin\left(\frac\pi2+v\right)\,dv=-\cos\left(\frac\pi2+v\right)+K$$
But when I put this into a computer algebra system, I got back $\sin v$. Why?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That's what I thought untill I put it in a CAS and it returned $sin(v)$ as the result??

Comment: What do you mean "when we have $\pi/2$"?

Comment: @Alex5207 Most likely, if you had included your thoughts in the original post (the details about having gotten something, but it not agreeing with a CAS), your question would have been more well-received. And while I'm here, I'll mention the cofunction identities $\sin(\theta) = \cos \bigl( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \bigr)$ and $\cos(\theta) = \sin \bigl( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \bigr)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $-\cos(x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin x$.

Comment: Note that I'm answering the original version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Either

(1) use a substitution $t = \frac{\pi}{2} + v$, or

(2) expand $\sin(  \frac{\pi}{2} + v) = \sin \frac{\pi}{2} \cos v + \cos \frac{\pi}{2}\sin v=\cos v$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Addition Formula for Sine, $$\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + v\right) = \cos v.$$

Then $$\int \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + v\right) \text{ } dv = \int \cos v \text{ }dv = \sin v + C.$$